# vncserver: geometry 800x600-depth is invalid on fedora

Tags: fedora, vnc-server

Anyone dan help me when item using vncserver "vncserver: geometry 800x600-depth is invalid"
And if i using other command, but just this waspada 
displayed 
"Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory "

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/sysconfig/vncservers please add if it's not added already:

> VNCSERVERARGS[X]="-geometry 800x600 -depth 16"

Dont forget to edit X to the number you are using, probably [1], restart vnc server and try again.

Comment: But, on text editor just viewed "/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.$rver.service"

Answer (score 0):

THIS FILE HAS BEEN REPLACED BY /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service

The resolution adjusting just defined in vncserver@.service

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 16 -geometry 800x600 :%i
```

Hit sudo systemctl restart vncserver@.service to activate changes.